# XSD extend a type, and add fields on top and on the bottom

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I have the following XSD (for the sake of asking this question):

```
  <xsd:complexType name="BaseType" abstract="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="field1" type="xsd:string"/>
      <xsd:element name="field2" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="ExtendedType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:extension base="tns:BaseType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="fieldA" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="fieldB" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:element name="extendedType" type="tns:ExtendedType"/>
```

This allows a XML file as follows:

```
<extendedType>
  <field1>hello</field1>
  <field2>world</field2>
  <fieldA>aaa</fieldA>
  <fieldB>bbb</fieldB>
</extendedType>
```

That is, the two news fields fieldA and fieldB are added at the bottom of the BaseType.

Is there a way to extend the BaseType,
but inserting fieldA on the top, and fieldB on the bottom?
so that this works?

```
<extendedType>
  <fieldA>aaa</fieldA>
  <field1>hello</field1>
  <field2>world</field2>
  <fieldB>bbb</fieldB>
</extendedType>
```

and how to make JAXB work as expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Below is the relevant statement in the XML Schema specification:

**2.2.1.3 Complex Type Definition** (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Complex_Type_Definition)

> A complex type which extends another does so by having additional
>   content model particles at the end of the other definition's content
>   model, or by having additional attribute declarations, or both.

---

To be valid against the XML schema the extended fields need to occur after the inherited fields.  The elements can be in any order when unmarshalled.  If you're starting from POJOs you can mark the parent class`@XmlTransient` so that the parents properties are treated as part of the child so that they can be included in the child's `propOrder`.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/jaxbs-xmltransient-and-property-order.html

Comment: hi; are you 100% sure that there is no way to have extended fields before the inherited ones? i am reading the XSD specification, and I don't find where it says that extended fields must occur after the inherited ones. http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Complex_Type_Definitions
(I need the BaseType to be declared in the XSD file, so the Java trick does not work here)

Comment: @DavidPortabella - 100% sure.  I have updated my answer with the relevant passage from the XML Schema specification.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan there's an errant "s" on the end of the anchor of your URL (which happens to also be a valid anchor for another section).

Comment: Is there a way to generate these @XmlTransient and @XmlType(propOrder = { ... }) annotations/ base classes, when starting from XSD? E.g. using a binding file?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#Complex_Type_Definition

> A complex type which extends another does so by having additional content model particles at the end of the other definition's content model, or by having additional attribute declarations, or both.
>
> - Note: This specification allows only appending, and not other kinds of extensions. This decision simplifies application processing required to cast instances from derived to base type. Future versions may allow more kinds of extension, requiring more complex transformations to effect casting.

Thus, when extending a type, fields are only added at the bottom.

A hack: the fields from the *extended* type occur at the top.  i.e. fields added to the extended type are added at the top. So, you could have three levels of types: a top "dummy" level (for top fields), a middle level with the fields you want to inherit, and a bottom level (for bottom fields).  A schema that imports this will define the bottom level - and `redefine` the top level. This will enable you to add fields at the top and the bottom.
The ***big*** *problem* with this is that it will also redefine the top level for all other types that extend it... so these extra fields will occur all over the place, which is probably not what you want.

Other alternatives include: avoiding the extension mechanism, and instead using `substitution groups` (but these need different element names); or creating your own polymorphism (`<choice>`) and inheritance (`<group ref="..."/>` at the top and bottom) within the element - but note that every choice must begin uniquely or fall foul of the UPA rule (since they won't be distinguished by attribute, like `xsi:type`).

*EDIT* I see another answer already covered this bit I'd already type all this, and there's some extra suggestions, so I might as well keep it.

Comment: hi, thanks for all the info; I am sorry that stackoverflow only allows to accept one answer.